# Website that allows users to interact via SMS (at a charge)

Tags: sms

Some time ago I was a user of a website that allowed its users to establish contact with each other - for free via email, or at a minor added cost if you wanted to sms the other person right away.

Does anyone have any idea what kind of system could be used for the peer-to-peer SMS-ing with an extra charge that benefits the website?

Atm thinking about the UK, but an international system would be even better.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Mobile phone companies allow you to sent email to mobile phones.  You generally need the mobile phone number and the name of the phone company.  Then you can send email to that number at that phone company.  For example `2125551212@message.alltel.com`.  Here is [a site that documents a bunch of companies and how to send an SMS via email](http://sms411.net/how-to-send-email-to-a-phone/)

There are also Email to SMS gateways that allow you to send email to any phone number at that gateway and have it delivered to SMS.  [Wikipedia has a list of Email to SMS Gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways)

There are also APIs that you can call to send SMS messages.  Here is a [SMS API that purports to be free](http://smsoveremail.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Any idea about Whatsapp bulk messages? @Stephen Ostermiller♦